# Different sort despite same collation in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, collation

I am getting different sort results for items with diacritics even though the collation being used is apparently the same.

So, after installing [Postgress.app](https://postgresapp.com/) in my mac box for development I create the following table:

```
create table names (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar
)
```

and then insert a few values

```
insert into names values (1, "Francisco");
insert into names values (2, "Ana");
insert into names values (3, "Ágata");
```

and then query them like so:

```
select name from names order by name;
```

I get a wrong sorting order like so:

```
Ana
Francisco
Ágata
```

I can confirm with

```
select datname, 
       datcollate
from pg_database;
```

that the `datcollate` value for all databases is `en_US.UTF-8`.

To help me debug this problem, I quickly spinned up an RDS instance, with same data, query and collation, but this time I get the proper expected sort order of:

```
Ágata
Ana
Francisco
```

What am I missing here, and how can I configuration postgres in my dev box to behave as expected?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The collation being used by RDS is also `en_US.UTF-8`, hence the title of the question of same collations (and database engines) and different sort order results. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses the operating system for its locales (at least with `libc` as the collation provider, otherwise `icu` may be used), and unfortunately, different operating systems give inconsistent sort results for the same UTF-8 locale names.

The fact that UTF-8 collations with Postgres.app doesn't sort as expected is an old open item on their issue tracker: [Problems with sort order (UTF8 locales don't work)](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/216). It can't really be fixed unless Apple fixes macOS, and so far it's not happening. See [Ordering differences between Postgres instances on different machines (same locale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370051) for a 2012 question on SO mentioning the problem.

> *What am I missing here, and how can I configuration postgres in my dev
>   box to behave as expected?*

Your options:

- use the same operating system for dev and production, possibly virtualized.
- use ICU collations. They sort the same across all operating systems, but as of PG version 12, they can be used only with explicit `COLLATE` clauses at the column or expression level (not at the database level).
- use the "C" or "C.UTF-8" collations, which sort binary-wise by codepoints. They don't provide a linguistically-aware sort order, but they're faster, immutable and consistent across operating systems.